# Как с помощью ID избежать повторного вывода одного и того же объекта на экран?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть массив объектов, который хранится `json` файле, у каждого объекта есть `id`.

```
[
    {
        "time": "1500058550",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "time": "1500058551",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

И мой `js` загружает сообщения с файла, скажем, каждые 5 cекунд (и выводит на экран) потому что туда могли добавиться новые объекты. Но загрузка с файла проходит таким образом что загружаются и новые и старые объекты. Как можно сделать проверку по `id` на то, был ли уже объект загружен или нет?

```js
callback(
  [{
      "time": "1500064939",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "time": "1500064940",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]);

function callback(respond) {
  setTimeout(function tick() {
    var timeNow = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
      var data = respond[i];
      var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
      var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);
      if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
        var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
        var res = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()].map(function(x) {
          return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
        }).join(":");
        var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
        $('#messages').append(rowClone);
        $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
      }
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 5000);
  }, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так : добавлять к элементу, который вставляем кастомный атрибут, например `data-id`, в него записывать `id` с нашего json, и в каждой итерации по 
json-ну, проверять, существует ли элемент с соответствующим значением `data-id`, если существует, пропускаем итерацию, если нет добавляем элемент на страницу

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  callback(
    [{
        "time": "1500064939",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "time": "1500064940",
        "id": 2
      }
    ]);
});

function callback(respond) {
  setTimeout(function tick() {
    var timeNow = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
      var data = respond[i];

      if ($('.time[data-id="' + data.id + '"]').length) continue;

      var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
      var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);
      //if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
        var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
        var res = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()].map(function(x) {
          return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
        }).join(":");
        var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
        $('#messages').append(rowClone);
        
        $('.time', rowClone).html(res).attr('data-id', data.id);
      //}
    }
    setTimeout(tick, 5000);
  }, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Или, создать массив, `id`, в который записывать добавленные значения и в каждой итерации просто смотреть в него, есть ли уже такой `id`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    callback(
        [{
            "time": "1500064939",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "time": "1500064940",
            "id": 2
        }
        ]);
});

var exists = [];

function callback(respond) {
    setTimeout(function tick() {
        var timeNow = Date.now();
        for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
            var data = respond[i];

            if (exists.indexOf(data.id) != -1) continue;

            var timeInMessage = data.time * 1000;
            var diff_time = (timeNow - timeInMessage);
            //if (diff_time <= 3600000) {
                var newDate = new Date(timeInMessage);
                var res = [newDate.getHours(), newDate.getMinutes(), newDate.getSeconds()].map(function (x) {
                    return x < 10 ? "0" + x : x;
                }).join(":");
                var rowClone = $('.mess_hide').clone().removeClass('mess_hide');
                $('#messages').append(rowClone);
                $('.time', rowClone).html(res);
                exists.push(data.id);
            //}
        }
        setTimeout(tick, 5000);
    }, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroller">
  <table id="messages">
    <tr class="mess_hide">
      <td class="time"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

UPD: закоментил `if (diff_time <= 3600000)` чтобы примеры работали :)

Answer (score 2):

Добавляй в вёрстку самого элемента `data` атрибут, например `data-message-id`, а потом делай проверку на этот самый атрибут, если таковой уже имеется на странице в потоке DOM - просто делай `continue` - если такого ещё нет - выводи на экран.

Comment: только `continue` вместо `return`, так как `return` полностью выйдет с функции, а надо пропустить только текущую итерацию цикла

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych Спасибо за замечание)